# How to require input args for first 3 params only and make the last param default?

Tags: powershell

I have a switch mechanism in my script and as can be seen,

> Add, RemoveRole, and RemoveMmember

I would like for them to REQUIRE the input of `$ROLE` and `$MEMBER`, which i know how to do with a conditional if statement, and would exit if nothing is entered. however, it would mean for `View`, which no input is necessary, to bypass this input requirement.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Add', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$Add,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveRole', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$RemoveRole,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveMember', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$RemoveMember,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$View,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Add', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveRole', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveMember', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$false)]

    $ROLE = (Read-Host -prompt "Role"),
    $MEMBER = (Read-Host -prompt "Member")
)
```

How can I make it such that input is required for the first 3 choices, but for view its not? also, how can i make View the default parameter choice if none of the choices is entered by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting Default parameter by specify:

```bsh
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='View')]
```

You can try the code below:

```bsh
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='View')]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Add', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$Add,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveRole', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$RemoveRole,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveMember', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$RemoveMember,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$View
)

if ($Add -or $RemoveRole -or $RemoveMember) {
    $ROLE = (Read-Host -prompt "Role")
    $MEMBER = (Read-Host -prompt "Member")
}
```